# Automatically created Forum vocabulary

Tags: 7

When I enable core forum module it does not automatically create "Forums" vocabulary in taxonomy and it uses another vocabulary instead.

I've tried to create Forums vocabulary manually and then assign it to 'Forum topic' content type from 'manage fields' tab like so:

[image]

[image]

but it still uses another vocabulary. I've tried everything that I found.

Note: The forum lists its topics from 'Service Types' vocabulary, even though I configured it to use Forums as I described above. I think the main problem here is that when I enable forum module it should automatically create the 'Forums' vocabulary, but for some reason it does not do it.

Comment: Sorry,It's unclear what you're asking. What do mean it still users another vocabulary?what's it? I've done the same steps, I see 'Forums' vocabulary. It's working as expected

Comment: The forum lists its topics from 'Service Types' vocabulary, even though I configured it to use Forums as I described above.

I think the main problem here is that when I enable forum module it should automatically create the 'Forums' vocabulary, but for some reason it does not do it.